# Htaccess - GET variable is lost

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to echo `$_GET['page']` but it seems like my htaccess makes it not work. The echo seems to appear and right away disappear from the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#page number
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# remove /index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]    

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: How are you doing the echo in PHP? What is your PHP code?

Comment: echo $_GET['page']; when I am on bragdeal.com/page/2

Comment: "appear and right away disappear" are you redirecting from that page?

Comment: flashing content does not sound like the result of an .htaccess redirect.  That sounds like javascript.